# Codeigniter allowed french uri charicters

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, php-7.3

So I have this unfortunate file manager app that accesses files by passing a file path to an api. Now I need to support the scenario where file paths and names could have french characters. So the url can look like:

`mysite/api/files/home/école%20du%20fromàge`

So my config is now `$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-()+Çéâêîôûàèùëïü';`

This works and allows the characters in my local environment, but not my live one, the live environment still throws the `The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.` error. So something differing in my environment between dev and prod is changing how this works.

Changing config to `$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = '';` will work and allow these characters, so it's something to do specifically with these french ones.

What could this be?

Edit:

Something I remember, before the french characters, I added `+` to the list to allow that as a valid character, and it worked, in both environments. So the changes are definitely taking effect, the config file on prod is definitely the correct one.

Comment: Development and production often have different configuration files. Did you make the change in both configuration files? Check application/config/production/config.php.

Comment: @Asrar Yes, I'm 100% sure the change is applied to both config files.